# Convert text to column or dataframe or another text

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Is it possible to turn two texts in a dataframe? Or either in a another text ?

I have one text like this:

```
['+49 69 1234 5678', '+49 30 9876 5432', '+49 89 2587 9852']
```

And another text like this, that is directly correlated to the first txt:

```
['Bruno', 'Hölzel', 'Anna']
```

Is there a way to generate a table like this:

```
+49 69 1234 5678 | Bruno
+49 30 9876 5432 | Hölzel
+49 89 2587 9852 | Anna
```

Or even another txt like:

```
['+49 69 1234 5678; Bruno', '+49 30 9876 5432; Hölzel', '+49 89 2587 9852; Anna']
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use list comprehension

```
a = ['+49 69 1234 5678', '+49 30 9876 5432', '+49 89 2587 9852']
b = ['Bruno', 'Hölzel', 'Anna']

['; '.join(i) for i in zip(a, b)]

['+49 69 1234 5678; Bruno', '+49 30 9876 5432; Hölzel', '+49 89 2587 9852; Anna']
```

To write this in a txt file, you could do:

```
f = open("my.txt","w")
[f.write('|'.join(i)+'\n')for i in zip(a,b)]
f.close()
```

Comment: hey says that the data is in 2 files not in a `python list`

Answer (score 0):

You can do like the Onyambu's answer or you can create a dataframe in pandas like this:

```
import pandas as pd
# My pd.__version__ is the 0.25.3

# Import the two txt file
dataframe_1 = pd.read_csv('filename_1.txt')
dataframe_2 = pd.read_csv('filename_2.txt')

# Concatenate the two dataframes on axis=1 (column)
dataframe = pd.concat([dataframe_1, dataframe_2], axis=1)

# You can export as a txt with different separator changeable in sep parameter
# You can also export without index and without header
dataframe.to_csv('test.txt', index=False, header=None, sep='|')
```

If you want more info about the function to_csv, you can explore the official documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)